# doctrine migrations configuration: kernel.project_dir is not interpolated

Tags: symfony, yaml, doctrine, doctrine-migrations, symfony-kernel

I'm trying to generate and execute migrations using `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`.

Project specs:

- Project deployed in docker. Mapping configured successfully.
- Framework: symfony.
- Kernel::getProjectDir() overrided successfully.
- Project dependencies (not all, only important for this topic) from composer.json:

  - ```json
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
    ```

My project has migrations for two databases. There are 2 config files for this. An example of one of them for understanding (absolute path in container */opt/app/config/packages/migrations/some_config.yaml*):

```yaml
custom_template: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/migration_template.txt' # <- this not works
# custom_template: '/opt/app/config/migration_template.txt' # <- this works
em: some_em
transactional: false
migrations_paths:
  'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/DoctrineMigrations' # <- this not works
  #'DoctrineMigrations': '/opt/app/src/DoctrineMigrations' # <- this works
```

**Problem:**

I'm trying to generate migration, using following command:

```bash
bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate --configuration='/opt/app/config/packages/migrations/some_config.yaml'
```

An exception is thrown with an message:

```
 The specified template "%kernel.project_dir%/config/migration_template.txt" cannot be found or is not readable
```

For absolute path everything works fine.

I have tried to debug doctrine-migrations package code and found, that path `%kernel.project_dir%/config/migration_template.txt`  does not turn into `/opt/app/config/migration_template.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the command is implemented in the doctrine/migrations lib and is unaware of Symfony, and therefore doesn't know about container parameters. The Doctrine migrations docs have an example for such a path, so you might try this:

'./src/DoctrineMigrations'

(didn't try myself though).

The relevant part in the docs is here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.6/reference/configuration.html#configuration